# ADD CONSTRAINT USING INDEX LOCAL

Tags: sql, oracle

Tenho uma tabela particionada por DATA_HORA e gostaria de criar a CONSTRAINT forcando o uso do INDEX LOCAL ao invés de GLOBAL, porém estou enfrentando o seguinte erro. Isso é possível?

```
Relatório de erros -
ORA-14039: colunas particionadas devem formar um subconjunto de colunas de chaves de um índice UNIQUE
14039. 00000 -  "partitioning columns must form a subset of key columns of a UNIQUE index"
*Cause:    User attempted to create a UNIQUE partitioned index whose
           partitioning columns do not form a subset of its key columns
           which is illegal
*Action:   If the user, indeed, desired to create an index whose
           partitioning columns do not form a subset of its key columns,
           it must be created as non-UNIQUE; otherwise, correct the
           list of key and/or partitioning columns to ensure that the index'
           partitioning columns form a subset of its key columns
```

Segue instruções para simulação.

```
CREATE TABLE TESTE_INDEX (
    "ID"         CHAR(65),
    "DATA_HORA"  TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL,
    "CODIGO"     NUMBER

  ) PARTITION BY RANGE ("DATA_HORA") INTERVAL (NUMTODSINTERVAL(1,'DAY'))
    SUBPARTITION BY HASH (CODIGO) SUBPARTITIONS 32
    (PARTITION POS_DATA_P0 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2020-11-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')))
;

ALTER TABLE TESTE_INDEX ADD CONSTRAINT "PK1_ID" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
USING INDEX (CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IDX1_PK ON TESTE_INDEX ("ID") LOCAL);
```